# Rounding integer in php to nearest upper integer

Tags: php, integer, ceil

I have the integer

```
$price = 19.999999995;
```

I want the php to print out any integers similar to $price integer to upper integer value which is "20".

```
$total = ceil($price);
```

I am expecting the above $total value to be 20 , but it's return "21".

How can i make that ? and why it's returning 21 instead of 20 .

Comment: erm, this outputs 20 when I tested it. If there is more related code then perhaps you ought to add that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function.

```
$price = 19.999999995;
$total = round($price);
echo $total;
```

As stated in the PHP documentation:

> Note that 'ceil' can show unexpected behaviour when using float values
>   due to inaccuracies in the float system and PHP tendency to freely
>   limiting the number of digits it displays to the user.